# Ionic Build Android - build.gradle file keeps adding duplicate compile line and causing build failure

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

In my Ionic 3 project, I followed [this guide](http://lokesh-patel.blogspot.it/2016/06/cordova-plugin-firebase-cloud-messaging.html) to see if I could get my Android project to compile, but anytime I try to run `ionic cordova build android`, I'm getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Cannot add task ':processDebugGoogleServices' as a task with that name already exists.
```

I'm not sure if this is an issue with FCM, but I've noticed that any time I run the build command, this line shows up in my `build.gradle` file

`compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2"` - Anytime I remove it, it keeps showing up with the rest of my compile statements like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Also, here is my `config.xml` for reference:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="<id-omitted>" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <author email="snstarosciak@gmail.com" href="http://iamstevie.me">
        Stevie Starosciak
  </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="cdvfile://*" />
    <access origin="file://*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.200.104:8100" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0" />
    <plugin name="Cordova-Plugin-FCMNotification" spec="git+https://github.com/LokeshPatel/Cordova-Plugin-FCMNotification.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="^0.9.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" spec="^2.29.21" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^2.4.1">
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.3.0">
        <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="22+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email" spec="^1.2.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^1.9.1">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="1233601713359527" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="Bandly" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm" spec="^2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^4.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.6.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-velda-devicefeedback" spec="0.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="git+https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" spec="^3.6.5" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="^4.0.1" />
</widget>
```

And here is my `project.properties` file from `/platforms/android`

```
# Project target.
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/app-xwalk.gradle
cordova.system.library.5=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+
cordova.system.library.6=com.android.support:support-v4:25.+
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+
cordova.system.library.8=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+
cordova.system.library.9=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2
cordova.system.library.11=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-fcm/app-FCMPlugin.gradle
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Try tweaking, the config.xml,  where these plugins are mentioned, it is possible that during build the config.xml is used to generate android specific  config files, and that end up overwriting the built files

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the suggestion. I was looking at my config.xml and I'm not entirely sure what I would need to tinker with in order to test things out. I've actually added my config.xml for reference. Is there anything there you could point in the right direction on?

Comment: Hi, can you post reference to file in /platform/android/project.properties, just check with that as well, you will get clue, if not post reference to it, i will check

Comment: Alright, I gotcha. It's there now :) Any clue?

Comment: Stevie - remove this line

cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2 and try, it seems to be duplicate, 

cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2
with
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+

Comment: Hey art, I tried doing what you recommended and I'm still getting that same error. Is this related to the Google FCM related plugins maybe?

Comment: Why is this duplicated in project properties? cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+ cordova.system.library.10=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+ I'd Google before deleting. Looks odd to me

Comment: Maybe you've somehow got two versions of firebase-messaging?

Comment: Is first code package.json? i have     "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8", "firebase": "^3.7.4", in my project - but haven't used firebase-messaging...

Comment: hey there JGFMK, I'm trying to figure out why there are duplicate ` cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-service‌​s-ads:+`. I've updated all of my Android Services and Google Services is up to date. I know this issue is caused by one of these plugins as I'm able to build the default Ionic Conference App to Android no problem

Comment: Sometimes this will help, completely remove platform android, and plugins and reinstall it, before that just run--> npm cache clean (--force if new version)

Answer (score 0):

It seems FCM gradle tried to apply the plugin, which is probably already being applied in your build.gradle file.

Follow the instructions below.

```
In FCM Gradle, comment the last line (below) that contains Googleservicesplugin
```

".\platforms\android\cordova-plugin-fcm\your_app-FCMPlugin.gradle"

```
buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' <---- COMMENT THIS LINE TOO, add to Root gradle file
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
//apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin <---- COMMENT THIS LINE
```